# Why does my form submit on second click instead of first click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When you don't enter a bitcoin address it throws an alert to enter a valid one, but when you enter a valid address you have to click the button twice for it to work. Any editing I try doing doesn't seem to work. Please help.

You can use this bitcoin address to test with:
1QEv2L5o5zNHDJDVHCydLh9ZNKp7qQM1Bc

https://jsfiddle.net/pd98046y/

```html
<script>
var reg = new RegExp("^[13][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,34}$");

    $('#button1').on('click', function() {
      var walletCheck = $('#wallet').val();
      if (reg.test(walletCheck)) {
        $('#button1').on('click', function() {

          var coinAmount = $('#bitcoin').val(),
            coinContent = 'BTC amount requested: ' + coinAmount,
            dollarAmount = $('#cad').val(),
            dollarContent = 'Market: $' + dollarAmount;
          feeAmount = dollarAmount * 0.08;
          feeContent = 'Fee: $' + feeAmount.toFixed(2);
          totalAmount = dollarAmount * 1.08;
          totalContent = 'Total: $' + totalAmount.toFixed(2);

          $('#btc-amount').html(coinContent);
          $('#cad-quote').html(dollarContent);
          $('#cad-fee').html(feeContent);
          $('#cad-total').html(totalContent);
          $("#step1").hide();
          $("#step2").show();
          $("#slogan").hide();
        });
      } else {
        alert("Invalid Bitcoin address, please make sure you've entered a valid address!");
      }
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the inner `$('#button1').on('click', function() {` and `});`?

Comment: Yes, but then it executes the else statement right away and the button becomes unclickable anymore.

Comment: Can you please help with valid bitcoin address?

Comment: 1QEv2L5o5zNHDJDVHCydLh9ZNKp7qQM1Bc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the mistake, had to remove `'#button1').on('click',` from the second `$('#button1').on('click', function() {` 
and now it works perfectly.